# FlutterFlow iOS swipe to get back gesture throws an error

Tags: ios, flutter, back, flutterflow

i am not able to find any solution on this issue. I am using FlutterFlow with the Default transition to navigate to a different page and i am always getting the following error on the Sim and on a physical device.

`Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/route.dart': Failed assertion: line 635 pos 12: '_backGestureController != null': is not true.`

I hope anyone had the same issues and was able to solve them.

Thanks for helping :)

Different transitions

Answer (score -1):

Resolved (somehow):

The problem only occurs when i have a hero image on the page enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).